# Find a column header on another sheet that a value matches on

Tags: google-sheets

I want to find a cell value that is in another sheet then return the column header (always minus 2 columns) that the cell value matches on.

In the example below I want a formula in `S402` that searches the sheet `lineups` for the same value and then gets the header AC1.

So If I search `lineups` for `Shantanu (#2L2V28CJG)` in the cell `S402` I want the value to be `#Ash Empire`

- The header I want is always 2 columns back from the column the match is in
- There is only EVER one match or no match
- The main sheet is called `signups`

I have tried query/match but just cant work it out. Thanks

**This is the signups sheet**
[image: searchsheet]

**This is the lineups sheet**

[image: lineupsheet]

Comment: Welcome. I might be missing something here... at present "Signups", Cell#S402 contains text = "Shantanu (#2L2V28CJG)". You want to change Cell#S402 so it doesn't contain text but has a formula that searches "Lineups" for the value "Shantanu (#2L2V28CJG)" and returns "#Ash Empire". Do you intend that "Shantanu (#2L2V28CJG)" will be hard-coded into the formula? If not, what is the location of the search key?

Comment: Regarding your search for a value on a another sheet, read [Search Entire Worksheet and Return Cell Value of the Matched Column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28308544/1330560) on StackOverflow. That answer includes "+1"; in your case, change this to "-1".

Comment: @Tedinoz NO I want Cell#S402 to end up with the value "Ash Empire" Its in the red text on image one!

Comment: What I do not understand is why the -2, if this is not clear please ASK rather than blindy give a vote down. This is so frustrating

Comment: Lack of research. Your StackOverflow reputation means you would be familiar with the conditions applying to questioners. Similar expectations apply on Webapps: [How do I ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). _Search and research: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?_ It probably took longer to write your question than it would have taken to apply the solution from [Search Entire Worksheet and Return Cell Value of the Matched Column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28308544/1330560) - which was sitting there in plain sight.

Comment: @Tedinoz I have done research and my comment `"I have tried query/match but just cant work it out."` means just that, I have tried and tried and keep failing, just because I have reputation doesn't always mean that a person should "get to the answer". Maybe Sheets is just not my thing, just be mindful of that. Thanks for answer though

Answer (score 1):

You want to search for a value ("Shantanu (#2L2V28CJG)")in another sheet and return the relevant column header (offset by two to the left = "#Ash Empire").

There is no provision for the search value to be available as a variable, so it is hard-coded into the formula.

Enter this formula into Sheet="Signups", Cell="C402"

`=INDEX(Lineups!$1:$1,0,SUM(IF(Lineups!$A$2:$E$5="Shantanu (#2L2V28CJG)",COLUMN(Lineups!$A$2:$D$4)-MIN(COLUMN(Lineups!$A$2:$D$4))-1,0)))`

**Sheet = Lineups**

[image: Lineups]

---

**Sheet = Signups**

[image: Signups]

Comment: I'd be interested in whether this formula works for you because the search variable is "lost" in the code of the formula. I _did_ notice an apparent relationship between "Endless Facepalm" and "Shantanu (#2L2V28CJG)" but that could be just a fluke.

Comment: No sorry @tedinoz it doesn't. Having a hard coded value just isn;t going to work.
In the end I am doing processing of sheet via the API and working out what I need in code. Thanks though

Comment: @Rippo You have an outstanding reputation on StackOverflow, so I hope you won't be offended when I suggest that this question was enigmatic. Looking back, you specified a formula-solution (though now its a script). And I did ask "Do you intend that "Shantanu (#2L2V28CJG)" will be hard-coded into the formula? If not, what is the location of the search key?" Your response didn't really address my question or help with a solution. FWIW, you mention the API though I wonder why common Apps Script wouldn't suffice. Best wishes with writing your solution

Comment: thanks for comment. This is a small piece of a large Jigsaw. The thing starts as a discord bot using c# that then stores data into a DB. At some point this data is written to Google Sheets via the API. A sheet is manually created by a human being and data copied around (lineups). After which I need to try and provide a way to see what data (cell) in "signups" that marries up to a column header in "lineups" for hundreds of rows. I tried a google sheets solution as it seemed the correct appraoch, but failed!  As I am already using code in first place it was fairly trivial to code in C#

Comment: As for the hard coded question, the value comes from `C402` (and for all rows in col c) and populates the answer in `S402`. The answer is always row 1 in the sheet `lineups` but the matched column is always -2 columns. So S402 will find the value B1 in your example, S403 might be the value of D1, S404 might be the value E1 etc

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense now.